# Tapestry XML output

Tags: java, xml, tapestry

I'm interested in the Tapestry framework put have some problems with it due to several reasons:

The output I have to generate has to be XML. According to http://tapestry.apache.org/content-type-and-markup.html this is no big deal.
But when it comes down to use actionlink, components or all the other Tapestry goodies, the resulting code should not be anchor or div but some custom xml elements/attributes.

Is it possible to archieve this without alot of pain?
Workarounds or insides to the background mechanismn of Tapestry are welcome.

Comment: Consider using Facelets instead of Tapestry.

Comment: what a useless comment steve h.

Comment: Arman, what use is an 'actionlink' when it is some arbitrary xml node? please describe what you are trying to achieve so people can better help you. thx.

Comment: I have to use an xml-wrapper for creating website which will be converted by a platform into device specific html code. Thus, I just can't use an anchor directly but the resulting href which I'd put in the corresponding attibute. For instance:

<t:actionlink t:id="start"></t:actionlink> <!-- this would be removed by the platform -->
<xyz href="/index.start">put here some text</xyz> <!-- this will do the same but is ugly -->

Without the actionlink the tapestry framework doesn't know anything about the start action and would return an error.

Comment: I want something like this
<xyz href="${actionLinkStart}">put here some text</xyz>
or at least no hardcoded final href which can break very easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while [actionlink](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/ActionLink.html) will always render as an anchor (a) tag, the [Any](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Any.html) component can render as any arbitrary xml element, and it and many other tapestry components will render arbitrary (informal) parameters depending on their definition.

for example, (assuming you have a java method called 'getTheTime' in your class, mine returns `System.currentTimeMillis()`)

```
<xyz t:type="actionlink" t:id="someaction">
    a element</xyz>

<xyz t:type="any"
        attribute1="${theTime}"
        attribute2="prop:theTime"
        attribute3="theTime">
    xyz element</xyz>
```

will render as:

```
<a href="/app/page.someaction">a element</a>
<xyz attribute1="1338418847753" attribute2="1338418847753"
        attribute3="theTime">xyz element</xyz>
```

In order to get a combination of the two, you will need to roll your own component. This is pretty simple once you understand tapestry a little better.

Have a look at the source of ActionLink.java (and its super classes) and you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: Ok, and how do I achieve that for example in the any-component <xyz attribute1 gehts the resulting value of an actionlink?
E.g. <xyz href="[VALUE HERE]">...</xyz>

Comment: This is all totally doable with tapestry, however if you are a beginner you might want to start with a simpler task and work your way towards using the framework in an 'alternative' manner.

Comment: Thx, I'll give it a try.
Things are somehow complicated due to our platform. Thus, doing things alternatively right away might be necessary. :/